# How to see interaction between two connected servers?

Tags: nginx, networking, server

Currently I am working on one work in which one nginx server is acting as front-end server and other nginx server is connected to this front end server to serve it what user has requested. Now, I can visualize the activities of user from the access log of front end server, but meanwhile, I want to know how this front-end server is interacting with that back-end server?
Is there any way to see, for example, by seeing some sort of log or any other procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Find where the second one stores its logs . access logs of back-end nginx is what the first one sends to it.

Comment: can we see how back-end server effects the performance of front-end server based on its resource utilisation i.e CPU and Disk performance